# Install4j: Can updater update itself?

Tags: java, install4j

I am using Install4j 6.1.1. I have an updater (which is actually a silent updater) that dose not follow install4j's conventional way of updating/ update checks. Now, There can be scenarios where I also have to update the Silent updater. So far on my research, there is an option to build an [addon-installer](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/). But it does not have any updater option. is there any way that I can make the updater update itself? Or any other way to update the updater and still the have the context values from the installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the updater downloads a new installer which contains a new version of the updater.

If, for example, you have modified the updater to only download and extract a ZIP file, the updater will not be updated itself.

Comment: so, if I make another project with the same application id, where I only have the updater and installer option of course, but without any action other than install files, will I be able to install the updater in unattended mode without any screens/popups? Also I am concerned about the proper context information.

Comment: in case my windows does not have the required jre, is it possible for the new installer to use the jre of the previous installation? that would reduce the size of the installer to a significant amount.

Comment: Yes, the installer will use the JRE of the previous installation automatically.

Comment: I created the installer without any jre bundled. And started the installer (in linux) and i got the following: "No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system. The version of the JVM must be at least 1.7. Please define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM."

Comment: I was hoping by not including any uninstaller to the new installer would keep the existing uninstaller unchanged. But after the new installation, although the project did not include any uninstaller, the uninstaller fails to instantiate with message: internal error: the selected application uninstaller could not be instantiated.

Comment: Indeed, you cannot do that, all installer applications are defined in .install4j/i4jparams.conf.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117730/discussion-between-shadoow-and-ingo-kegel).